# Placed library in /usr/lib, but ldconfig doesn't put it in cache

Tags: shared-library, linker

I'm starting a project that requires an external shared library `third-party.so`.

I've placed it in `/usr/lib`. However, when I run `sudo ldconfig -v`, it's not listed.

`ldconfig -p | grep third-party.so` proves that it wasn't added to the cache.

Does this mean that there is something wrong with the library? Or am I missing some detail? I've run `readelf` on it, and it didn't detect any surprises. Running `file /usr/lib/third-party.so` returns:

> /usr/lib/third-party.so: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64,
>   version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

Comment: -v should work. It is possible as the manual states that the library has not sufficient information to be processed automatically.

Comment: I've run `sudo ldconfig -v 2>&1 | grep third-party` and the library isn't processed at all.

Comment: Would you please add a `file yourlib.so` output to your question?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: ok, posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An older colleague of mine took a look and gave the solution: the .so must have a **lib** prefix:

> **lib**third-party.so